# How to use observables in Durandal?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I am fairly new to Durandal. I have a little experience with KnockoutJS. I am trying to populate an observableArray from json retrieved from a php file. I am then trying to load the array into a table. There seems to be an issue when loading the data into the table upon first load of the page. I perform a system.log(customers) just to make sure the data is in the observableArray, which it is. When I refresh the page, the data is loaded into the table like I want it to. It appears as if the observableArray is getting populated, but the view is not updating.

I was wondering what I am doing wrong for it to not load on the first load of the page. Here is the test site I've been playing with durandal: http://dev.codeplanetapps.com/spa/. Once it loads, click on "Customers." The page in question is http://dev.codeplanetapps.com/spa/#/customers. When that page is loaded directly, it works fine, but when I load the app from the main page and then switch to customers, it doesn't load the table correctly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the view:

```
<div>
<!-- Form to add new customer -->
<form class="form-inline customerForm">
    <span>Add New Customer</span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: inputName" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" class="date input-small" data-bind="value: inputDOB" placeholder="Date of Birth" />
    <input type="text" class="input-small" data-bind="value: inputPhone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: inputEmail" placeholder="Email" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: submitCustomer">Add</button>
</form>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered customerTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: dob"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" data-bind="click: $root.removeCustomer">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the viewmodel:

```
define(function(require){ 
    // Load System for debugging
    var system = require('durandal/system');

    // Customer Structure
    function Customer(data) {
        this.name  = ko.observable(data.name);
        this.dob   = ko.observable(data.dob.substring(5,7) + '/' 
            + data.dob.substring(8,10) + '/' + data.dob.substring(0,4));
        this.phone = ko.observable(data.phone);
        this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
    };

    // Form observables
    var inputName  = ko.observable('');
    var inputDOB   = ko.observable('');
    var inputPhone = ko.observable('');
    var inputEmail = ko.observable('');
    // Customers array
    var customers = ko.observableArray([]);

    return {
        inputName: inputName,
        inputDOB: inputDOB,
        inputPhone: inputPhone,
        inputEmail: inputEmail,
        customers: customers,
        // This performs any needed functionality after the page loads
        activate: function(data) {
            // Change the selected nav item 
            $('.customerNav').addClass('active');
            $('.firstNav').removeClass('active');
            $('.secondNav').removeClass('active');

            // Get current customers from database and add to customers observableArray
            $.getJSON(
                // Backend script
                'php/query.php', 
                // Variables sent to query.php
                {
                    mode: 'select', 
                    table: 'customers', 
                    'fields[]': '*', 
                    'values[]': '*'
                }, 
                // Callback function
                function(data) {
                    var customer = $.map(data, function(item) {return new Customer(item) });
                    customers(customer);
                }
            );

            // For some reason I couldn't get the datepicker to work without make the page 
            // wait 50 milliseconds.
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('.date').datepicker();
            },500);
        }
    };
});
```

Also, as a side note, the jQuery at the top and bottom of the activate function only work when I surround them in a setTimeout() function. I left the datepicker as an example. It's not as crucial, but if anyone knows how to fix that, too, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks, Paul. I was up late last night. I forgot to reply to add the answer. I got an answer from Rob Eisenberg, the creator of Durandal. My mistake was that I needed to return the promise from the .getJSON() call. I also needed to add another function, viewAttached(), to the module for all of my jQuery calls that refer to an element in the DOM.

Here is Rob's reply to [Help with observableArray not updating in view](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/_x78N1KGlpc). They are really helpful in this group. Rob is pretty quick to answer most questions.

Below is the corrected code for the viewmodel:

```
define(function(require){ 
// Load System for debugging
var system = require('durandal/system');

// Customer Structure
function Customer(data) {
    this.name  = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.dob   = ko.observable(data.dob.substring(5,7) + '/' 
        + data.dob.substring(8,10) + '/' + data.dob.substring(0,4));
    this.phone = ko.observable(data.phone);
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
};

// Form observables
var inputName  = ko.observable('');
var inputDOB   = ko.observable('');
var inputPhone = ko.observable('');
var inputEmail = ko.observable('');
// Customers array
var customers = ko.observableArray([]);

return {
    inputName: inputName,
    inputDOB: inputDOB,
    inputPhone: inputPhone,
    inputEmail: inputEmail,
    customers: customers,
    // This allows us to add jQuery as usual
    viewAttached: function() {
        // Change the selected nav item 
        $('.customerNav').addClass('active');
        $('.firstNav').removeClass('active');
        $('.secondNav').removeClass('active');

        $('.date').datepicker();
    },
    // This performs any needed functionality after the page loads
    activate: function(data) {
        // Capture the module instance
        var self = this;

        // Get current customers from database and add to customers observableArray
        var promise = $.getJSON(
            // Backend script
            'php/query.php', 
            // Variables sent to query.php
            {
                mode: 'select', 
                table: 'customers', 
                'fields[]': '*', 
                'values[]': '*'
            }, 
            // Callback function
            function(data) {
                var customer = $.map(data, function(item) {return new Customer(item) });
                system.log(customers);
                self.customers(customer);
            }
        );

        return promise;
    }
};
}); // define
```

Comment: Thank you, smalone. That is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I've learned a lot about Durandal in the few weeks I've been working with it. It's been a life saver for developing single page applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've changed anything since posting the question, but it works for me in IE 9, Opera 12 and Chrome. There is an error thrown in IE 9, `lines 45 and 46` of `shell.js`, `event.currentTarget.classList` is sometimes null, so you should check that, but if I go to your app and click on Customers, there is data in the table.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I posted it as a solution above. Thanks for checking though.